# uploading a file from the user's PC to my server using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0

I created a simple .Net 4.6 site with an asp:FileUpload and asp:Button control so that users can browse their PC for a file, and then upload it to my server.

I've gotten the first part down as you can see below.  However, I don't know how to get the user's file to my server.  It's just a Windows Server 2012 with IIS installed.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<asp:FileUpload CssClass="upload" ID="flImageFromComputer" runat="server" />

<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" CssClass="btn" />

Protected Sub btnUpload_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpload.Click

Try
    If Me.flImageFromComputer.HasFile Then
        With Me.flImageFromComputer
        ' *** not sure how to get it to the server ***
        End With
    End If

Catch ex As Exception
    Response.Write(ex.ToString)
End Try
```

I've tried Googling, but can't really find anything on how to transfer the file to my server.

Any help would be great!  :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing a google search, I suggest you look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload?view=netframework-4.7.2). You would see that it contains a [SaveAs method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas?view=netframework-4.7.2). It should do what you are looking for.

```
Me.flImageFromComputer.SaveAs("c:\...\file.ext")
```

You'll have to make sure the running user has access to the path.

Comment: Thanks! I actually did see that, but  assumed it was used to save to the users PC and not my server.

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell ah! well, the vb part is run on the server. Read up on the difference between client side and server side code. It can be confusing with web app.